# Safari cuts animation on form submit

Tags: javascript, css, safari, drupal-7

There appear to be a lot of questions about this, but none that have provided a working answer so far.

We have a css animation that animates an ellipsis using this fine example.
https://codepen.io/thetallweeks/pen/yybGra

The class we use is here

```
#edit-submit.loading:after {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(4,end) 00ms infinite;
  animation: ellipsis steps(4,end) 900ms infinite;
  content: "\2026"; /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.25em;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.25em;
  }
}
```

And since we need this animation to appear *during* form processing we use the following JS

```
        $('#my-form').bind({
          submit: function (e) {
            var submitButton = $('button[type=submit]');
            if(!submitButton.hasClass('loading')) {
              e.preventDefault();
              console.log('adding!');
              submitButton.addClass('loading');
              setTimeout(() => {
                e.target.submit();
              }, 4000);
            }
```

What you see above allows the animation to run as predicted for about 4 seconds (the set timeout) and then the animation freezes in its tracks.

Is there any way to prevent Safari to ignore its normal prerogative and allow this animation to proceed until the user is on the next page?

Comment: To clarify, it needs to run while the form is being processed not before or after

Answer (score 1):

This is an interesting problem. I was going to suggest using `animationend` on the loading element (the submit button). However, it's a step animation that keeps going infinitely. My solution is to add a second animation which does nothing except wait for 4 seconds. I then attach `animationend` to wait for that "animation" to end and finally submit the form.

```js
$('#my-form').bind({
  submit: function (e) {
    console.log('submit')
    var submitButton = $('button[type=submit]');
    if(!submitButton.hasClass('loading')) {
      e.preventDefault();
      console.log('adding!');
      submitButton.addClass('loading timer');
    }
  }
})

$('#edit-submit').on('webkitAnimationEnd oAnimationEnd animationend', function() {
  alert('submitting form');
  // $('#my-form').submit();
});
```

```css
#edit-submit.loading:after {
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: bottom;
  -webkit-animation: ellipsis steps(4,end) 00ms infinite;
  animation: ellipsis steps(4,end) 900ms infinite;  
  content: "\2026"; /* ascii code for the ellipsis character */
  width: 0px;
}

#edit-submit.timer {
  animation: timer 4s forwards;  
}

@keyframes timer {
  to {
    opacity: 1;
  }
}

@keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.25em;
  }
}

@-webkit-keyframes ellipsis {
  to {
    width: 1.25em;
  }
}

#edit-submit {
  font-size: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form id="my-form">
   <button id="edit-submit" type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lqpejky2/3/)

Comment: No Luck using this method :( once I uncomment the form submit and actually submit the form, its death to the animation.